# Racket: How to enable source location tracking for exceptions?

Tags: exception, location, racket

When I run Dr.Racket with a faulty expression such as

```
(/ 1 0)
```

I see an error message along with its source location.

However, running

```
(with-handlers ([exn:fail? exn:srclocs?])
  (/ 1 0))
```

reveals that the source location is not set. How does Dr. Racket enable source location tracking for exceptions?

Comment: See the documentation for `errortrace`, which DrRacket uses when debugging is enabled: http://docs.racket-lang.org/errortrace/index.html

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I need the value of exn:srclocs. Using errortrace gives me a stacktrace (for the first expression) but exn:srclocs remains unset.

Comment: What makes you think DrRacket uses `exn:srclocs?`? I don’t think that exception ever reports source location information that way. (I believe `exn:srclocs?` is usually used by compile-time errors, not runtime ones.)

Comment: Seems that I was on the wrong track, but thanks for the clarification. I rephrase my question: When evaluating a syntax object (enriched with source locations) raises an exception, what is the idiomatic way to retrieve the location where the exception occured?

Comment: You can use `exn-continuation-marks` to get the continuation marks for an exception, then you can use `continuation-mark-set->context` to get the builtin stacktrace information, and you can use `continuation-mark-set->list` combined with `errortrace-key` from `errortrace/errortrace-key` to get errortrace’s stacktrace.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!